# HashMap<String, ArrayList<Objects>>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>` how do I add elements into it form a GUI and how can I retrieve them and store them in a JTable in the GUI.

Getting a class cast exception . See code snipped below

```
public ArrayList<Vendor> getVendors(){
    ArrayList<Member> vendorList = new ArrayList(vendors.values());

    return new ArrayList(vendorList);
}
```

This is how Vendor class is defined and vendors object used as well below

```
public class Vendor {
    private String vendorName, vendorDescription;
```

vendors is a HashMap

```
  private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Vendor>> vendors;
```

Comment: You gotta show some effort. Either an attempt or show you've done research.

Comment: This question is too broad. You have to be more specific!  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> I have a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>` how do I add elements into it form a GUI

You write UI code that creates the keys and objects, and calls `Map.put(...)`.

> .... and how can I retrieve them and store them in a JTable in the GUI.

You write code that iterates the `Map`, and populates a `TableModel`.

And before you ask, I'm not going to provide you with "example" code to copy.  Sorry.

---

Re your followup question:

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Vendor>> vendors;
...
ArrayList<Member> vendorList = new ArrayList(vendors.values());
```

The type of the value returned by `vendors.values()` will be `Collection<ArrayList<Vendor>>`, but you are attempting to use it in a context that requires a `Collection<? extends Member>`.  Obviously `ArrayList<Vendor>` and `Member` are not related types!

I don't understand why that would give you a class cast exception, but it is definitely wrong.

Comment: This is the best generic answer such a generic question could hope for.

Comment: Question modified to include code as well. Pls help comment